# Proving the non-uniform convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to show that the series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} e^{-kx}\sin(kx)$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0, \infty)$.

To do so would require a special case of the Cauchy criterion; that is, if a series $\sum^{\infty}_{1} f_{n}(x)$ is uniformly convergent on some interval $I$ then $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $I$. To show non-uniform convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{1} f_{n}(x)$ over $I$, we simply want to show that $f_{n}(x)$ does not converge to 0 uniformly on $I$. For example, $\sum^{\infty}_{1} x^{n}$ is non-uniformly convergent over $|x|<1$ since $x^{n}$ does not converge to 0 uniformly over $|x|<1$.

However, I am having trouble doing this for my case. Could someone show the best way to do this?

Comment: you mean $e^{-kx} $ ??

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum e^{-kx} \sin(kx) = \sum g_n $ converges uniformly on $[0, \infty)$, then

$$ \lim \sup_{x \in [0, \infty)}  |g_n(x)| = 0 $$

But notice since $e^x \geq x + 1 \iff e^{-x} \leq \frac{1}{x+1} $, then

$$ e^{-nx} \sin(nx) \leq e^{-nx} \leq \frac{1}{1 + nx} \leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

A uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. As $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, the limit should be $0$ at $x=0$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there would exist $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ and $0\leq x<1/n_0$, $|f_n(x)|<1/n_0$. But if
$$
x_n=\frac\pi{2n},
$$
you have $f_n(x_n)=1$ for all $n$.